# How to build a simple NodeJS login using Microsoft OAuth

Tags: node.js, azure, oauth

I have followed this tutorial (https://medium.com/authpack/easy-google-auth-with-node-js-99ac40b97f4c) to create a simple Google OAuth and I have accomplished it successfully.

Now I am trying to do the same with Microsoft and I cannot.

I have ready a lot of posts about it, but I am failing.

I have one app in the Azure Dev Portal, I have tried to send the user to the URL `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={{my_clien_id}}&response_type=code id_token&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/email`, but I am receiving error messages only.

How can I have the user email using the Microsoft OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for user email accounts as AD user accounts or office 365 accounts then you can go for Azure Active directory app.
If you are considering social logins like facebook or google or Microsoft then you need to search for Azure Ad B2C. 
Here are some article which can help you:

1. [Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-microsoft-account#:%7E:text=To%20use%20a%20Microsoft%20account,www.live.com%2F.)
2. [Azure AD](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs)